# WinRM self signed cert for azure VM

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault, winrm

Looking for examples on how to generate a self signed cert using either the Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates library, or generating a standalone cert and importing it into azure keyvault. My intention is to use this cert to connect to an azure VM over winrm.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to create certifictae

```html
// Create a certificate. This starts a long running operation to create and sign the certificate.
CertificateOperation operation = client.StartCreateCertificate("MyCertificate", CertificatePolicy.Default);

// You can await the completion of the create certificate operation.
// You should run UpdateStatus in another thread or do other work like pumping messages between calls.
while (!operation.HasCompleted)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    operation.UpdateStatus();
}

KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = operation.Value;
```

Please refer this to find some examples. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates/samples

Reference to configure WinRM With HTTPS in azure virtual machine

https://techdiksha.com/configuring-winrm-azure-virtual-machine/